# auto select an item from a jquery autocomplete field

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I'm using a jquery autocomplete (plugin v 1.1) in an older application. It works fine. I'm now writing a new one and I'm using the jquery ui 1.4.4 version of autocomplete. In the 1.1 version, if I typed *izza* and the only match in the resulting list was *pizza*, then *pizza* would be highlighted and clicking **enter** would select pizza. The newer version will not do this. *Pizza* will show up alone in the list but I still have to arrow down, or click it to select it. Is this a lost feature or is there a property that activates *'auto-select'*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Gonzalez has an extension that will do this. You can find it [here](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js).

It worked perfectly.